# Past and present participles grammar rules

Tags: grammar, past-participles

Do past and present participles
always have to have an auxiliary
verb?

Comment: No: what makes you think they do?

Comment: Please give us some examples, to understand better your question.

Answer (score 2):

No, they don't always come with auxiliary verbs since they can function as adjectives to describe nouns and subjects in sentences for example.

The present participle: is a word that an -ing is always attached to it. There are three cases of it in sentences.

*Note:* The present participle is in **bold** in all of the following examples.

---

**The first case:** It functions as an adjective to describe subjects/nouns.

Example:

> The **winning** team is going to have a trip to London as a reward.

---

**The second case:** It takes place in a progressive/continuous actions.

Examples:

> The boy was **eating** his meal when the doorbell rang.

- It has the auxiliary verb "was". The sentence is in the *past progressive tense*.

> The child is **playing** in the schoolyard currently.

- It has the auxiliary verb "is". The sentence is in the *present progressive tense*.

> They will be **singing** within an hour from now.

- It has the auxiliary verbs "will & be". The sentence is in the *future progressive tense*.

*Note:* The different tenses of the sentences are not related explicitly to the *present participle*; I have mentioned their types for you to notice the different forms that can contain a *present participle*.

---

**The third case:** It can function as a noun which is known as a gerund.

Example:

> **Partying** at night can be so much fun!

---

The past participle has slightly different cases (nearly the same ones) but you get the idea. I recommend [this article](https://www.dictionary.com/e/whats-a-participle/) to read about it as I have covered the present participle part.